# Can i terminate debugging session in Qt with a shortcut

Tags: qt, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

That's a nuisance to always go to the menu or close debugging application manually. Can i do it with a shortcut like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> in VS?

Would be nice also to be able to terminate and restart debugging session with a single shortcut like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd> in VS, but that's a secondary ask?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In QtCreator go to menu `Tools->Options...->Environment` in `Keyboard` tab find `Debugger` section, select `Stop` or `Reset`, double click on it and set your keyboard shortcuts